# команды установки графических оболочек Linux

Tags: linux

какие команды вводить в терминале для их установки ?

Comment: Обратитесь к документации вашего дистрибутива за ответом

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vJAjvb2xmGs

Comment: Телепаты в отпуске, а мы не знаем, ни какой у вас дистрибутив, ни какую оболочку вы хотите поставить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tasksel` для дебиана и убунтоидов.